# datePicker showing one day previous wrong day in grails

Tags: grails, datepicker

In edit and print (html print) mode, I have get one day previous date. I have used mysql database. My domain like

```
class Immunization {
    ------
    Date   doseOneDue 
    Date   doseOneGiven
    ----
}
```

I have use datepicker in view like

```
<g:datePicker name="doseOneDue" precision="day" noSelection="['': '']"
              value="${immunizationInstance?.doseOneDue}"
              relativeYears="[-5..5]" default="none"/>
```

**Now problem is:**
suppose doseOneDue is '2015-08-30', But when I showing it in datePicker in edit mode then it is selecting '29 - 08 - 2015', Also in html print option showing also one day less. How can handle this problem.

Comment: Since you're not using it, have you tried removing _noSelection_?

Comment: I am using noSelection: sometimes I need to set null date.